# How do I read CSV file row by row and update Python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, csv, iteration

I have the following Python 2.7 script:

```
import urllib as ul
tracking_id = "abcde=="
encodedtrackingid = ul.quote(tracking_id)
mcid = "123456"

URL = "https://example.com/id?abcd&d_mid="+mcid+"&=124"+encodedtrackingid+"%011"
print URL

from mechanize import Browser
br = Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
response = br.open(URL)
print response.read()     

import requests

url = "https://example.net/rest/v1/mbox/4513452615415"

querystring = {"client":"example"}

payload = "{\r\n              \"mbox\" : \"example\",\r\n\"CloudVisitorId\":\""+mcid+"\",\r\n              \"thirdPartyId\": \""+tracking_id+"\",\r\n              \"contentAsJson\": \"true\",\r\n                             \"mboxParameters\": \r\n                             {        \r\n                             \"mboxMCGLH\": \"6\"     \r\n                             }\r\n}\r\n"
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "289879f645d-1543-e6df-87fb-1cef88f55110c5"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

What I want to do is the following:

a) Repeat this script by updating the tracking_id and the mcid variable from a CSV file.

The CSV file has no headers and has the following columns:

Column: A - tracking_id
Column: B - mcid

I need the script to read the CSV file run the script for row 1, then repeat the same process for row2, row3, row4 etc. Each time the script runs the tracking_id and the mcid variable updates, and the output of the response variable is stored into a CSV file.

The end result would be a CSV file  that would have the following:
Column A - tracking_id
Column B - mcid
Column C - response

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: import csv start here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would wrap the initial script up in a function (`myfunction` in the code below) taking the `tracking_id` and the `mcid` as parameters and returning the value you wish to retrieve.

```
import csv

# Loading csv
with open("mycsv.csv", 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    # Reading row by row
    for row in reader:
        tracking_id = row[0]
        mcid = row[1]

        # Getting result
        result = myfunction(tracking_id, mcid)

        # Opening csv result file in append mode
        with open("mycsv_result.csv", "a+") as csv_save:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_save)
            writer.writerow([tracking_id, mcid, result])
            csv_save.close()
```

Then this script should do the trick.

---

EDIT :

Here is the function missing. I also suggest you to [read this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) in order to learn how to create basic functions.

```
def myfunction(tracking_id, mcid):
    import urllib as ul

    encodedtrackingid = ul.quote(tracking_id)

    URL = "https://example.com/id?abcd&d_mid=" + mcid + "&=124" + encodedtrackingid + "%011"
    print
    URL

    from mechanize import Browser

    br = Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    response = br.open(URL)
    print
    response.read()

    import requests

    url = "https://example.net/rest/v1/mbox/4513452615415"

    querystring = {"client": "example"}

    payload = "{\r\n              \"mbox\" : \"example\",\r\n\"CloudVisitorId\":\"" + mcid + "\",\r\n              \"thirdPartyId\": \"" + tracking_id + "\",\r\n              \"contentAsJson\": \"true\",\r\n                             \"mboxParameters\": \r\n                             {        \r\n                             \"mboxMCGLH\": \"6\"     \r\n                             }\r\n}\r\n"
    headers = {
        'content-type': "application/json",
        'cache-control': "no-cache",
        'postman-token': "289879f645d-1543-e6df-87fb-1cef88f55110c5"
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

    return response
```

Comment: Thanks - how do I wrap the initial script into a function?

Comment: I get an error saying:   File "functiontest.py", line 46, in <module>
    result = myfunction(tracking_id, mcid)
TypeError: myfunction() takes no arguments (2 given)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the function code :) I am getting errors saying unexpected indent. I am copying your code above, any ideas what's causing it?

Comment: Yeah, you probably have an extra tab somewhere. Go from an empty python file, copy/paste the function code, leave two empty lines, and copy paste the csv script part. It should work fine then.

Comment: Great i've managed to find the error. Thanks for your help! Sorry, one final question. The output of the response looks like this:  

{"thirdPartyId":"SpxLjiBdWMju78AzIHns2XMrrcpkt1YJSfM73hmYabyFxsaWdodG5pbmdzZWVkcw==","VisitorId":"89027979811717493914206190290951066813","edgeHost":"example.net","content":{"tnttfsVal":"2345:4:0","contentName":"examplecontent"},"sessionId":"4513452615415"}

How would I just grab the contentName value?

Comment: Assuming you store the response in a variable called response, you should manage to get it by calling response["contentName"]

Comment: You are a legend! Nice one. Also, any idea why my CSV file output keeps skipping a row?

Comment: response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print response["contentName"]  -- I get an error saying response object has no attribute ' _get item_'

Comment: Ok so I have managed to stop it skipping rows by adding 'ab' instead of 'a+' It's just the response["contentName"] that I am struggling with now.

Comment: Try response["content"]["contentName"]

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv


#traceroute
traceroute_output = """
185.86.232.2     0.512 ms    0.453 ms    0.414 ms
188.95.232.58    0.795 ms    0.765 ms    0.731 ms
188.95.232.67    1.493 ms    1.463 ms    1.560 ms
188.1.239.85     1.853 ms    1.827 ms    2.001 ms
"""
reader = csv.reader(traceroute_output.splitlines(), delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)

for row in reader:
    if len(row)< 7:
        #neglecting invalid values
        continue
    key_value = row.pop(0)
```

Here is some sample code which wrote some time ago to parse the CSV file separated by spaces, You can modify according to your requirements. I hope this will be useful.

Comment: Thanks - struggling to apply to my scenario. Any tips?

Comment: How does your sample csv file look, Is it a comma separated file? or space separated